# How to get Cmd-Tab (Mapped to Alt-Tab) in a Parallels Windows VM to cycle just Windows Apps?

Tags: parallels-desktop, keybindings

I have a Windows VM running in Parallels and is working just fine. I have mapped Apple-<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key to Windows-<kbd>Alt</kbd> and Apple-<kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd> to Windows-<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>.

When I press <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> - even in full screen mode - I cycle through all Apps running in both Windows and MacOS. How do I get it to just be Windows?

Answer (score 7):

To disable the OS X system keyboard shortcuts while the focus is on your VM, just change the setting under Shortcuts labelled "Send OS X system shortcuts" to Always.  This will send all keystrokes *only* to the VM when it has the focus.

[image: Screenshot of keyboard settings]

Comment: This preference seems not to exist on Parallels 11 ...

Comment: Correct, I dont see that option in Parallells 11

Comment: I don't see this in Parallels 12 either. I could really use something like this.

Comment: I updated the screenshot and explanation to Parallels 12.  It's all still there, just the setting looks a little different.

Comment: @jbandi Open "Parallels Desktop Control Center" (that's where all your VMs are lister), click on gear icon for your VM, click "Hardware Tab", click "Mouse and Keyboard" entry, click "Open Shortcut Preferences..." button.

Comment: It's in Parallels 17. under shortcuts, 'mac os shortcuts', in the control center preferences (not vm-specific configure options)

Answer (score 2):

This has moved again in Parallels 13.  You can now find it by:

1. Clicking on the settings gear icon in the Control Center
2. Click the `Hardware` Tab
3. Click the `Mouse & Keyboard` entry
4. Select the maxOS System Shortcuts
5. Change the "Send MacOS system shortcuts" from Auto to Always
6. (if needed) Allow Parallel to control System Accessibility and enter in your password

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me in Parallels 19:

- Parallels Control Center > Parallels Desktop (menu) > Preferences
- Shortcuts > macOS System Shortcuts > Send macOS system shortcuts: Always

[image]